# Retrieving image from sqlite to imageview android throws error

Tags: android

Below is my code for retrieving images from a sqlite database in Android. but it throws error after the last line

```
Database = Dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();  
String selectQuery = "SELECT Distinct  image from Image where year =1997 and QuestionNumber=1";

c = Database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
c.moveToNext();

byte[] bb = c.getBlob(0);

ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream); 
image.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

after the last line, it throws error

What have I missed?

Comment: share the logcat error

Comment: Open the DDMS persepective, then the logcat view, and post the thrown exception

Comment: Refer this library https://github.com/svenkapudija/Android-ImageResizer, If you are getting OutOfMemoryError.